# Content Management Api to POST media files from external source

Tags: episerver

I am looking for a solution in episerver to add media files from external sources into episerver.I am aware that episerver has recently released Episerver Content Management API to post contents within Episerver.Is it possible to use this for media files as well.As this is newly introduced in episerver, i cant find any references other than the documentation within epi which has more of CRUD operations on Content.Can someone please point out some reference links for me to get this started?

Any input is appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The content management API is useful if you want to create a headless website that talks to Episerver via an API to get content.

Depending on what you want to use the media for will depend on the optimal approach.  I assume you want the content editors to be able to pick these items from within the CMS?  If so there are two main appraoches:

You could write a scheduled task using the content repository API to import the media into the Episerver media library

The other option is to create a content provider, so the media is available in the editor, read [this](https://www.jondjones.com/learn-episerver-cms/episerver-developers-tutorials/episerver-customizing-episervers-ui/how-to-display-non-episerver-content-within-the-episerver-editor/) to learn how to do it.  This option is more fidley so I would go with option 1 if possible.

If you just want to render images on a web page, then call the API using AJAX.  Job done!

Comment: Thanks for the response Jon. The approach u mentioned is either to store bulk upload in one go or for the editor to work with media within EPiServer. Hope I got that correct :)

Comment: Also, yes I am working on creation of headless website that talks to epi via APIs to work with the content. The delivery requirement is easily achievable using Content Api as there are quite a few implementations guidelines that I can refer to. Additionally, another requirement that I need is to use EPiServer as a kind of repository to store/perform CRUD on media files from an external application & this is where I am looking for some implementation guidelines related to content management Api as this is what will help me achieve this requirement. Hope I am making sense here.